# Why is episode 2 of "We Rent Tsukumogami" called "Gardenia"?

Tags: we-rent-tsukumogami

Episode 2 of "We Rent Tsukumogami" (*Tsukumogami Kashimasu*) is called *Kuchinasi* (梔子, or "Gardenia"). It centres around the culture of hanging scrolls and their use at ceremonies (e.g. flower viewing or tea ceremonies) as a conversation piece, noting some of the popular imagery and characters.

While the symbolism of a few different elements of the scrolls is discussed, I don't remember them actually referring to gardenias, and even if they did it's not a major plot point. Instead, the more important discussion is about the relative value of a scroll with the moon on it, and its relevance to the story of Princess Kaguya.

The only connection I can find between Kaguya and gardenias is a long shot - in the Japanese language of flowers (花言葉), the gardenia represents "secret love", and the resolution of the episode does involve the characters realising that

> she longs to be able to see the moon
>  but I feel like that's a long shot, especially since it's never explicitly stated in the episode.

Is that the meaning of the title, or is there something I missed?